# Pushing AWS Lambda data to Kinesis Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Is there are way to push data from a Lambda function to a Kinesis stream? I have searched the internet but have not found any examples related to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can send information from Lambda to Kinesis Stream and it is very simple to do. Make sure you are running Lambda with the right permissions.

1. Create a file called kinesis.js, This file will provide a 'save' function that receives a payload and sends it to the Kinesis Stream. We want to be able to include this 'save' function anywhere we want to send data to the stream. Code:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const kinesisConstant = require('./kinesisConstants'); //Keep it consistent
const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({
  apiVersion: kinesisConstant.API_VERSION, //optional
  //accessKeyId: '<you-can-use-this-to-run-it-locally>', //optional
  //secretAccessKey: '<you-can-use-this-to-run-it-locally>', //optional
  region: kinesisConstant.REGION
});

const savePayload = (payload) => {
//We can only save strings into the streams
  if( typeof payload !== kinesisConstant.PAYLOAD_TYPE) {
    try {
      payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  let params = {
    Data: payload,
    PartitionKey: kinesisConstant.PARTITION_KEY,
    StreamName: kinesisConstant.STREAM_NAME
  };

  kinesis.putRecord(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else     console.log('Record added:',data);
  });
};

exports.save = (payload) => {
  const params = {
    StreamName: kinesisConstant.STREAM_NAME,
  };

  kinesis.describeStream(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
      //Make sure stream is able to take new writes (ACTIVE or UPDATING are good)
      if(data.StreamDescription.StreamStatus === kinesisConstant.STATE.ACTIVE
        || data.StreamDescription.StreamStatus === kinesisConstant.STATE.UPDATING ) {
        savePayload(payload);
      } else {
        console.log(`Kinesis stream ${kinesisConstant.STREAM_NAME} is ${data.StreamDescription.StreamStatus}.`);
        console.log(`Record Lost`, JSON.parse(payload));
      }
    }
  });
};
```

2. Create a kinesisConstant.js file to keep it consistent :)

```js
module.exports = {
  STATE: {
    ACTIVE: 'ACTIVE',
    UPDATING: 'UPDATING',
    CREATING: 'CREATING',
    DELETING: 'DELETING'
  },
  STREAM_NAME: '<your-stream-name>',
  PARTITION_KEY: '<string-value-if-one-shard-anything-will-do',
  PAYLOAD_TYPE: 'String',
  REGION: '<the-region-where-you-have-lambda-and-kinesis>',
  API_VERSION: '2013-12-02'
}
```

3. Your handler file: we added the 'done' function to send a response to whoever wants to send the data to the stream but 'kinesis.save(event)' does all the work.

```js
const kinesis = require('./kinesis');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('LOADING handler');
  
  const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err || res,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  
  kinesis.save(event); // here we send it to the stream
  done(null, event);
}
```

Comment: Great example, helped me a lot. Please just correct typo (small) - kinesisConstants.js - you missed last "s" in filename

Comment: This is a great example. But I cant help but wonder, what is the advantage of using Kinesis here.
If you are passing data to Lambda, why not just push to the storage (EG: Elastic Search) directly?
Why use a third party tool when most AWS storage tools have their own Node lib? It is more performant?

Comment: With this code, you will get `LimitExceededError` 's when sending more than just a few events as the DescribeStream method is heavily limited. According to doc its 10 req/sec. So rather remove the DescribeStream call

Answer (score 5):

This should be done exactly like doing it on your computer.

Here's an example in `nodejs`:

```
let aws = require('aws');
let kinesis = new aws.Kinesis();

// data that you'd like to send
let data_object = { "some": "properties" };
let data = JSON.stringify(data_object);

// push data to kinesis
const params = {
  Data: data,
  PartitionKey: "1",
  StreamName: "stream name"
}

kinesis.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log("data sent");
}
```

Please note, this piece of code **will not** work, as the `Lambda` has no permissions to your stream. 
When accessing `AWS` resources through `Lambda`, it is better to use `IAM` roles;

1. When configuring a new `Lambda`, you can choose existing / create a role.
2. Go to `IAM`, then *Roles*, and pick the role name you assigned to the `Lambda` function.
3. Add the relevant permissions (`putRecord`, `putRecords`).

Then, test the `Lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done, I was trying to accomplish the same thing and was able to do so in Lambda using Node.js 4.3 runtime, and it also works in version 6.10.

Here is the code:

Declare the following at the top of your Lambda function:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis();
function writeKinesis(rawdata){
    data = JSON.stringify(rawdata);
    params = {Data: data, PartitionKey: "<PARTITION_KEY>", StreamName: "<STREAM_NAME>"};
    kinesis.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else console.log("data sent");
    });  
}
```

Now, in the exports.handler, call the function:

```
writeKinesis(<YOUR_DATA>);
```

A few things to note... for Kinesis to ingest data, it must be encoded. In the example below, I have function that takes logs from CloudWatch, and sends them over to a Kinesis stream.

Note that I'm inserting the contents of buffer.toString('utf8') into the writeKinesis function:

```
exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    ...
    var zippedInput = new Buffer(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function(error, buffer) {
        ...
        writeKinesis(buffer.toString('utf8'));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, in IAM, configure the appropriate permissions. Your Lambda function has to run within the context of an IAM role that includes the following permissions below. In my case, I just modified the default lambda_elasticsearch_execution role to include a policy called "lambda_kinesis_execution" with the following code:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
    "kinesis:*"
],
"Resource": [
    "<YOUR_STREAM_ARN>"
]
```